# Fully connected transverse field Ising

Tags: ising-model

Can someone explain to me what a "fully connected transverse field Ising" is ?

I know what a classical Ising model is and I think the transverse term refers to the magnetic field being transverse to the spins am I right ?

But what exactly does fully connected means ? And how is it translated in term of hamiltonian ?

Answer (score 2):

I would *guess* that it means
$$
H=\sum_{n=2}^N\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}Z_nZ_m+\lambda\sum_{n=1}^NX_n,
$$
i.e. the Ising terms act between *every* pair of qubits.

Comment: But how can two qubits which are on the x-axis or on the y-axis for instance interact if we only consider the Pauli Z for the interactions here ?

Comment: Have you ever tried taking a 2-qubit transverse Ising model and evolving s separable state in time? Does it stay separable for all time? (No)

Comment: I lack understanding on those kind of things. Do you have some ressources to improve my knowledges on what you just said ?